# Не получается связать данные из БД с RecyclerView через CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cursor, recyclerviewadapter

Пытаюсь связать данные из своей бд с RecyclerView с помощью CursorAdapter и RecyclerViewAdapter. С ListView проблем НЕ БЫЛО, но мне нужен именно RecyclerView. Нашёл решение в интернете: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412986/recyclerview-adapter-with-cursoradapter . По идее должно было помочь, но я где-то допустил косяк который никак не могу обнаружить. Я когда добавляю новый элемент в БД, он должен отображаться в RecyclerView, но это не работает. Можете мне помочь с решением, вот код, что не так? Что вы думаете? Может есть более подходящие решения для этого?

Код activity с RecyclerView:

```
public class SavedActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int ENTRY_LOADER = 123;

    private RecyclerView dataRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    EntriesCursorAdapter entriesCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved);

        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        dataRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dataRecyclerView);

        entriesCursorAdapter = new EntriesCursorAdapter(this, null);

        dataRecyclerView.hasFixedSize();
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        dataRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        dataRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        dataRecyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("idRecyclerView", String.valueOf(view.getId()));

                Intent intent = new Intent(SavedActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                Uri currentEntryUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Entry.CONTENT_URI, view.getId());

                intent.setData(currentEntryUri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(ENTRY_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        /* Два последующих метода отвечают за вывод данных из бд. Но, для того
        * чтобы вывести какие-нибудь данные, их для начала нужно ИЗВЛЕЧЬ из бд - для этого
        * применяется метод query(). В этом методе как раз таки он и используется. */


        String[] projection = {
                Entry.KEY_ID,
                Entry.KEY_TITLE,
                Entry.KEY_TEXT
        };

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                Entry.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        entriesCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        entriesCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Класс RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.
        RecyclerViewViewHolder> {

    /* Заполнение RecyclerView данными из базы данных. */

    public static int adapter_position;

    private Context context;
    private EntriesCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    public static RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        cursorAdapter = new EntriesCursorAdapter(context, null);
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView titleTextView;
        TextView textTextView;

        public RecyclerViewViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            textTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTextView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = cursorAdapter.newView(context, cursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent);
        viewHolder = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewViewHolder holder, int position) {
        cursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        cursorAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView, context, cursorAdapter.getCursor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cursorAdapter.getCount();
    }
}
```

Класс CursorAdapter:

```
public class EntriesCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter  {

    public EntriesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.recycler_view_item, viewGroup, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Entry.KEY_TITLE));
        String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Entry.KEY_TEXT));

        title = title.length() > 15 ? title.substring(0, 15)+"..." : title;
        text = text.length() > 25 ? text.substring(0, 25)+"..." : text;

        RecyclerViewAdapter.viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(title);
        RecyclerViewAdapter.viewHolder.textTextView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите скриншоты и вставьте код текстом - здесь так принято и так всем проще, можно скопировать код в ответ и исправить, вместо того чтобы набивать его вручную (что отбивает желание вам помочь)

Comment: Во первых да - код должен быть текстом, картинки совсем не подходят. Во вторых - вы используете ряд технологий, которые не стоит использовать в силу их неудобства и устарелости. Для БД возьмите либу Room, данные оттуда будет просто классами, их можно напрямую в RecyclerView передавать. Обновления данных в БД можно через LiveData или, лучше, через RxJava (хотя это и сложнее) получать. В этом случае вам не понадобятся и дико неудобные и официально устаревшие лоадеры.

Comment: Я не вижу у вас кода, где в базу что-то добавляется и реакции на это добавление. При изменении базы курсоры не обновляются сами по себе - и с `ListView` было тоже самое. Если у вас всё же есть этот код, то `swapCursor()` обновляет `CursorAdapter`, но `RecyclerView.Adapter` не знает об изменении - нужно его уведомить вызовом `notifyDataSetChanged()`. И вообще вы в `RecyclerViewAdapter` создаёте внутренний экземпляр `EntriesCursorAdapter`, а `Loader` отдаёт данные экземпляру, созданному в `onCreate()`

Comment: Я бы не стал вязать два адаптера из разных эпох - что мешает работать с курсором напрямую в `RecyclerViewAdapter`? Можно подсмотреть реализацию того же `CursorAdapter` и сделать свой, современный.

Comment: @woesss БОЖЕ СПАСИБО ВАМ ЭТО ЗАРАБОТАТЛО УРА ВЫ ГЕНИЙ!! АХХВЫАЗХЫВА, ПРОСТИТЕ)). Просто это такое удовольствие когда что-то наконец начинает работать .. . Всё оказалось гораздо проще чем я себе придумал. Ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swapCursor() обновляет CursorAdapter, но RecyclerView.Adapter не знает об изменении - нужно его уведомить вызовом notifyDataSetChanged(). В RecyclerViewAdapter создаётся внутренний экземпляр EntriesCursorAdapter, а Loader отдаёт данные экземпляру, созданному в onCreate().